# Visual Studio Code do not start over Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

After upgrading Docker/Docker-Desktop to 4.0.0
i'm not able to start Visual Studio Code over Docker-Desktop.

Docker Desktop show an error: `Error invoking remote method 'desktop-go-backend': Error: Internal Server Error`

and if i start Visual Studio Code not over Docker Desktop, Visual Studio Code can not connect to WSL.
Console Output come with an error like this:

```
/home/xxxx/.vscode-server/bin/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/bin/code: not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching in outer issues with VS Code and WSL, i found the solution for me:

I delete the directory: `/home/xxxxx/.vscode-server/` in the WSL/Distribution

because the `directory /home/xxxxx/.vscode-server/bin/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/` was empty

After deleting the directory and restart VS Code the needed files are reinstalled and all working like before.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with a similar message:

```
Error invoking remote method 'desktop-go-backend': [object Object]
```

I managed to fix this by [removing the spaces in my source code folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71490425/docker-desktop-error-when-clicking-on-open-in-visual-studio-code#71774427).