# Docker Desktop error when clicking on "Open in Visual Studio Code"

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use Docker Desktop with VSCode. However, when I click on "Open in Visual Studio Code", I get the error below. What can be the cause of this?

**Error invoking remote method 'desktop-go-backend': Error:{"message":"cannot open editor: exit status 1 -"}**

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to open? vscode is good at editing text files. but not binary.

Comment: @LeiYang It's a folder with a lot of HTML and py files.

Comment: can you describe you detailed steps from running docker to open vscode?

Comment: @LeiYang I just open Docker and then I click on "Open i Visual Studio Code". Then the error occur.

Comment: open docker -- open what docker? why do you click on "Open i Visual Studio Code" open what?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, in my case it was a problem with spaces in the directory name. I changed that to "-", everything works again.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my similar error `Error invoking remote method 'desktop-go-backend': [object Object]`.